# Parse.Query find() method not returning anything

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform

I've reviewed the other stack overflow posts on this topic and it looks like I've run into something new.  The query method in question is not on the user table.

When I query for distance or many of the other columns in the mBuilding object I get undefined even though the columns are clearly there and I copy and pasted the column title into the function to check for spelling. From what I've seen, the only queries that work are get with the objectId and find. equalTo, select, withinMiles (at the least) are returning null/undefined results. What's even more interesting is that even though the query preceding find() is undefined it affects the find result appropriately. This is really bewildering.

What's going on here? My code:

```
angular.module('startupApp')
.controller('warrantyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.Building = {};

    $scope.Building.parseUserId = Parse.User.current().id;
    console.log($scope.Building.parseUserId);
    var consumer = Parse.User.current();
    var user = Parse.Object.extend("User");
    var warrantys = Parse.Object.extend("warranty");
    var mBuilding = new Parse.Query(warrantys);
    var consumerQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);

    $scope.consumerBuilding = function() {
        var location = consumer.get("location");
        mBuilding.withinMiles("location", location, "distance");
        mBuilding.find({
            success: function (proximalwarrantys){
                console.log(proximalwarrantys);
            }
        })
    }
    $scope.consumerBuilding();

});
```

Comment: The code looks fine. There must be some other issue going on. Is the "warranty" class name correct and the column names correct?

Comment: The column names are positively correct. I copied and pasted them from Parse to the code just to be sure. For the purpose of this question warranty is extraneous - I commented it out with no effect.

Comment: the distance should be a number and not "distance". [Api Docs](https://www.parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Query.html#withinMiles)

Comment: Wait, "distance" is a number in each Parse object. It should be sorting for warrantys within "distance" to the consumer (location).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the distance passed to the `withinMiles` function should be a number and not `"distance"`:

`withinMiles(key, point, maxDistance)`

> Add a proximity based constraint
>   for finding objects with key point values near the point given and
>   within the maximum distance given. Radius of earth used is 3958.8
>   miles.
>
> Parameters:
>
> `{String} key`
>   The key that the Parse.GeoPoint is
>   stored in.
>
> `{Parse.GeoPoint} point`
>   The reference Parse.GeoPoint that is
>   used.
>
> `{Number} maxDistance`
>   Maximum distance (in miles) of results to
>   return. Returns:
>
> `{Parse.Query}` Returns the query, so you can chain
>   this call.

[Parse API Docs](https://www.parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Query.html#withinMiles)

Comment: I know this from the docs.  "distance" is a number in the appropriate parse object that is acting as the max Distance for this query.

Comment: What do you mean? If you need data from an object you  would need to use `get("location")` on the appropriate object and then pass that in.

Comment: What if I have an array of locations to evaluate for distance?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. What do you mean by evaluate for distance? I'm guessing you would need to loop through the locations and then perform a query for each one?

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. Nothing is so simple. Would you mind helping me with the question of the moment: I'm trying to do a _.map to return the Parse objectId of a query.  I can return any of the fields accept for objectId. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You should just be able to use `object.id` to get the id. It's one of the three special values provided as properties. [Docs](https://www.parse.com/docs/js_guide#objects-retrieving)

Comment: True but I'm trying to get the object.id for each object in an array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70837/discussion-between-wayne-ellery-and-rashadb).

Comment: Click on the link "continue this discussion in chat"